# Jquery Shorthand if else code return undefined variable 50% of the time

Tags: jquery, shorthand

WHY does this work

```
var hash = "find.asp?find=something"
var findParam = hash.indexOf('=') ? hash.split('=')[1] : hash;

$('#test').html(findParam);
```

RESULT: "something"

But THIS doesn't ?

```
var hash = "something"
var findParam = hash.indexOf('=') ? hash.split('=')[1] : hash;

$('#test').html(findParam);
```

RESULT: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

The only difference is the variable.
If the variable contain '=' it should be treated one way, and if not...

https://jsfiddle.net/3eLan1hv/9/

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it:
like this:

```
var findParam = (hash.indexOf('=') != -1) ? hash.split('=')[1] : hash;
```

I added != -1 to the control and voilá

Comment: And because... Only `0` resolves to "falsy" and indexOf will return -1 when not found. When using indexOf you should always check for -1 and not for truthy or falsy. Test with `!!'something'.indexOf('=')` in the browser console to cast falsy/truthy to bool.

Comment: you can use `hash2.indexOf('=') > 0` also